# Define all functions using the main statement

Tags: integral-equations

Define all functions that are continious and fullfill the equation

$$ f(x) = -1 + \int_0^{x^2} \frac{(f(\sqrt{t})^2 \sin t}{\cos^2t} dt$$

I'm completely lost on this one. I think that you should use:

$$ S(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt $$ in some way.

Comment: Could you please provide some background for the problem? i.e. Where is it from?

Comment: @Golbez it's from an exam and more information is not provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iveqy

Using fundamental theorem of calculus we get:
$~f'(x)=\frac{f^2(x)sinx^2}{cos^2{x^2}}2x$. This yields $\int{f^{-2}}df=\int{}tanx^2secx^2xdx~$. So, we have, $\frac{-1}{f(x)}=secx^2+c$ . But $~f(0)=-1$. Therefore,$~c=0$ and $f(x)=-cosx^2$.